# Problem of connection apache directory studio

Tags: windows, apache-directory

I have install apache directory studio but the server dosen't open and I had this error when I create a new connection.

```
Une erreur est survenue lors de l''ouverture de la connexion
 -  ERR_04110_CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_SERVER Cannot connect to the server: Connection refused: no further information
org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.StudioLdapException:  ERR_04110_CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_SERVER Cannot connect to the server: Connection refused: no further information
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.toStudioLdapException(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1350)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.access$2(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1342)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper$1.run(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:258)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1261)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.doConnect(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:280)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.connect(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.jobs.OpenConnectionsRunnable.run(OpenConnectionsRunnable.java:111)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.jobs.StudioConnectionJob.run(StudioConnectionJob.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.exception.InvalidConnectionException: ERR_04110_CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_SERVER Cannot connect to the server: Connection refused: no further information
    at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.close(LdapNetworkConnection.java:781)
    at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.connect(LdapNetworkConnection.java:978)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper$1.run(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:227)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:669)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:944)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketConnector.finishConnect(NioSocketConnector.java:223)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketConnector.finishConnect(NioSocketConnector.java:47)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoConnector$Connector.processConnections(AbstractPollingIoConnector.java:571)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoConnector$Connector.run(AbstractPollingIoConnector.java:456)
```

Comment: A connection refuse message will most likely mean that either the address and port you are connecting to is being blocked or filtered for whatever reason, or nothing is running on the specified address and port.

Comment: How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the jvm I install the jdk 11 and I open the configuration file of apache directory studio to add vm and the local path of jdk folder and I add this \javaw.exe

```
-vm
E:\Repositories\Jdk11.0.12\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: What is the name of the file you edited and what is the file extension?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem. Base on Takwa answer I had already solved this problem.
The property file path is `{Apache Directory Studio Home}/ApacheDirectoryStudio.ini`

In this file disable `-vm` mark and add `java.exe`.
And I also found that, not all version after Java 11 JDK can work.
In my case I first try JDK 17 will occur this error.
After I edit the property file and set the JDK version 11 this error will not happend.

[image: My property example]
[image: My property example]

Answer (score 0):

I installed Apache DS on an EC2 instance, but the connection port was configured by default to 10389. After changing the port on Apache Studio it connected.