# Connecting LDAP server via public IP as hostname using Apache Directory Studio

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server, apache-directory

I have this dedicated VM server for LDAP. It has public IP (eg. 103.193.176.10) and Apache Directory Studio installed on it.

I've set the server as default and use 389 port as we see on [the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlMsF.png). If I connect into the same client as the server with the hostname as localhost, [it's connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhIgf.png). But I want to connect the LDAP server into different client and using the public IP as hostname.

I've tried to connect it from different and the same client using the public IP, but its [not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcUWm.png). I've [changed the hostname address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CbD0.png) into the public IP but when I try to run the LDAP Server, it's stopped and not running. I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847039/problem-of-connection-apache-directory-studio) and it's not working as well.

How can I do it properly? Should I just use Active Directory from Windows Server?